# REGEX HELP to insert string in header

Tags: regex, cookies

I'd like to insert the safety preference `PREF=f2=8000000` in an outgoing cookie for youtube. Can someone please help with the regex required. Please see the cookie header without it and with it below:

#### Original:

```
SID=DQAAAOYAAABOR9H2kgqMkq1kw7rbRguqB6DNJPQxTP0zN4grw27QbTf_vzBKkiXPCE6Jof7kVtt8RrY72G8tV6LyolxU5rQNQwYtuJunHZ__7ueW4lkiZ89vmnloUhw3nsrkrg4QQIdvMhhys4ubR2yjWwqq6SYK4yL0LNq2HRP3UD5cGzDA_CQ_Vxn9g1tAdrZpcn5aQCOctWLrRV-cG23Rz3A6CH-2Fvfqt_VdX1QqBio5hiY6BD5SLFKzQr9hsgPQ61pY_bA2hgSzphPA8Ui0l4wdru-zG2jwlJ3tbtJ3dq3QIdoVHnmfVxt8rICS0GBun3iltVY; HSID=ANIIq2v5699ch1oGG; APISID=xXQlULDSZ9YV9cWf/Ax_rCe3I9FzrH0bDA; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=m46yOEoBrtU; LOGIN_INFO=9f010d0f2ad7425d84ae06a16d0aa294c34AAAB7IjgiOiAxMzc0NDk3NjUxODksICI3IjogMTM5MTUxMzA4MCwgIjYiOiBmYWxzZSwgIjUiOiAwLCAiNCI6ICJHQUlBIiwgIjMiOiAzMzAxNDc1ODUsICIyIjogIlk0cTlxY2pPaUo1RzN4VThGWEl1dHc9PSIsICIxIjogMX0=; PREF=fv=12.0.0&f1=10000000&al=en-GB; YSC=Qf6d6pKHmTQ; ACTIVITY=1391513121453
```

(See the PREF=f2=8000000 included at the end.)

#### Desired

```
SID=DQAAAOYAAABOR9H2kgqMkq1kw7rbRguqB6DNJPQxTP0zN4grw27QbTf_vzBKkiXPCE6Jof7kVtt8RrY72G8tV6LyolxU5rQNQwYtuJunHZ__7ueW4lkiZ89vmnloUhw3nsrkrg4QQIdvMhhys4ubR2yjWwqq6SYK4yL0LNq2HRP3UD5cGzDA_CQ_Vxn9g1tAdrZpcn5aQCOctWLrRV-cG23Rz3A6CH-2Fvfqt_VdX1QqBio5hiY6BD5SLFKzQr9hsgPQ61pY_bA2hgSzphPA8Ui0l4wdru-zG2jwlJ3tbtJ3dq3QIdoVHnmfVxt8rICS0GBun3iltVY; HSID=ANIIq2v5699ch1oGG; APISID=xXQlULDSZ9YV9cWf/Ax_rCe3I9FzrH0bDA; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=m46yOEoBrtU; LOGIN_INFO=9f010d0f2ad7425d84ae06a16d0aa294c34AAAB7IjgiOiAxMzc0NDk3NjUxODksICI3IjogMTM5MTUxMzA4MCwgIjYiOiBmYWxzZSwgIjUiOiAwLCAiNCI6ICJHQUlBIiwgIjMiOiAzMzAxNDc1ODUsICIyIjogIlk0cTlxY2pPaUo1RzN4VThGWEl1dHc9PSIsICIxIjogMX0=; PREF=f2=8000000&f1=10000000&fv=12.0.0&al=en-GB; YSC=Qf6d6pKHmTQ; ACTIVITY=1391513121453
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In perl:

```
s/(.+PREF=)(.+)/$1f2=8000000&$2/
```